# Remove XML node in C#

Tags: c#, xml

My XML file looks like this:

```
<root>
    <files>
        <filesource uploadName="20180131T083441_638_Test.doc" originalName="Test.doc">c:\uploadDir\20180131T083441_638_Test.doc</filesource>
        <filesource uploadName="20180131T083441_638_Test1.doc" originalName="Test1.doc">c:\uploadDir\20180131T083441_638_Test1.doc</filesource>
        <filesource uploadName="20180131T083441_638_Test2.doc" originalName="Test2.doc">c:\uploadDir\20180131T083441_638_Test2.doc</filesource>
    </files>
</root>
```

C# code:

```
// fileNodes has all 3 files sources
XmlNode filesNodes = xmlFile.findNode("/root/files"); 

List<string> filenames = new List<string>();
filesname.add("c:\uploadDir\20180131T083441_638_Test.doc");
filesname.add("c:\uploadDir\20180131T083441_638_Test1.doc");
```

Whatever variable `filenames` contains, I want to keep it in XML file and the rest I want to delete.

Comment: I would suggest using LINQ to XML, which makes this sort of thing a lot easier. Please try that, and show how far you've got in terms of finding elements where the value in the element is present in the list.

Comment: If not using LINQtoXML as Jon suggested, the other easiest option would be to set `filesNodes.IsEmpty = true` - this will clear the files node - and then adding the nodes that you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used xml linq.  Had to remove the folder name from the file name to get code to work

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication23
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> filenames = new List<string>();
            filenames.Add(@"c:\uploadDir\20180131T083441_638_Test.doc");
            filenames.Add(@"c:\uploadDir\20180131T083441_638_Test1.doc");

            List<string> baseFilenames = filenames.Select(x => x.Substring(x.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1)).ToList();

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<XElement> filesources = doc.Descendants("filesource").ToList();

            foreach (XElement filesource in filesources)
            {
                string uploadName = (string)filesource.Attribute("uploadName");
                if (!baseFilenames.Contains(uploadName))
                    filesource.Remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```